# Glassfish server SQL erro

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've made a Java EE application in netbeans (glassfish server 4.1.1) with JPA.
It works perfectly fine on localhost.
The app doesn't work on a remote Glassfish server (4.1.1) when I export it as a WAR file and place it in the "autodeploy" folder of glassfish.
The app is accessible (pages without mysql connection work) but pages with connection to a database (a remote AWS RDS db server) don't work, it gives me the following error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT ID, password, username FROM USER
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="User.findAll" referenceClass=User sql="SELECT ID, password, username FROM USER")
```

Of course my database is open from connection to any IP ...

I don't understand why it doesn't work ...

Thank you very much !

Comment: `USER` is a reserved table and keyword in `MySQL`,you need to change the table name

Comment: @lucumt Seems legit but why did it work on localhost then ?

Comment: Maybe when you start it locally, it uses a Derby in-memory database instead of MySQL?